# Get Facebook username

Tags: facebook

I am trying to write a small application to learn about developing for Facebook and I was trying one basic command, to say (Welcome, user_name).

I used:

```
 Welcome, <fb:name uid='<?php echo $user; ?>' useyou='false' possessive='true' />!
```

but it did not work, do you know what should i use?

Comment: What do you see?  Are you sure $user is a valid UID?

Comment: yeah, and i can't see anything, it prints an empty space there. I used the code from the facebook api

Comment: actually i tried $fb_user as they say here : http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP
and it still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this through a canvas application or Facebook Connect?

In either case, it's probably one of two issues: Either (A) the Facebook object is being fired up with the wrong api key or secret, or (B) you haven't authorized the application, so there's no UUID coming through.

Calling this before that code of yours should fix both:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_API_KEY,YOUR_SECRET_CODE);
$user = $facebook->require_login();
```